# App MapFragment locked into modal when using Bottom Sheet Dialog

Tags: android

I've created a Bottom Sheet Dialog that slides up when a button is pressed, and I'd like to populate that dialog with clickable links; basically, you click on the text, and the map centers and zooms to the new location, and the dialog closes. However, when the bottom sheet is "up", the map becomes modal, so that you cannot interact with it. Can anyone help?

This is my code so far:

```
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);

View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_layout, null);

dialog.setContentView( view );

TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.splo ); // This is the id of the bottom fragment xml file

SpannableString string = new SpannableString("My home");
string.setSpan(new ClickableSpan(){
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // mMap is the map fragment

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(51.503396, -0.12764)));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}, 0, 6, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

tv.setText( string );

dialog.show();
```

Also, another question if I may; I assume you can mix spannablestrings and strings, for instance, having a heading (string) and then a list of clickable strings (spanned) below?